# Sorting test results on Tests tab in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

*I admit I am creating a duplicate from [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1365077/sorting-test-results-on-tests-tab-in-azure-devops-pipeline) because there seem to be more Azure-DevOps users here*

I run frontend tests for a webapp using WebdriverIO/Selenium as a nightly build defined in the Pipelines section of Azure DevOps.

For each build I can view test results on the `Tests` tab, which will show me statistics on all tests and a list of tests that I can filter and group.

[image: Azure DevOps Tests tab statistics and filter options]

Until a few days ago, this list was automatically sorted alphabetically, now it is not sorted in any obvious way. I cannot find any option to sort the list, and the [Azure DevOps page on reviewing test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=vsts) does not mention sorting at all. I have also not had any luck using Google.

Is there a way to sort this list, e.g. by test name? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on some other sub menu (such as Logs) and click on the test tab it is sorting to name order. However if you do any selection order gets changed to what you have mentioned.

Alternative option is you can view the test runs in the Test tab. In there you are able to sort by columns. All your pipeline based test results also available in the Test hub --> Runs

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "click back and click on the test tab". Also, my "tests" are not defined as a classical test in DevOps, but as a nightly build that publishes test results in the end. So my test result list is under <Project name> / Pipelines / Builds / <Build name> / <Build #> / Tests

Comment: Updated to make it clear. I added new navigation screenshot. Your nightly builds test runs should be available in test runs in the Test hub. It is not the ideal solution to your problem of sorting the result in the pipeline result view. But same result set is available in the test hub..in Runs.. so you can do sorting when you open a given test run

Comment: Seems like that's the only way to go, even though accessing the details of the single test cases is much "harder" from the Test Runs view than from the Builds. But it'll do.

Comment: yes @Raketenolli it is bit harder..but only available alternative for now.